# Python. Если встречается определенный символ в строке, начиная с последующего за ним добавлять в другой список\строку

Tags: python

Здраствуйте.

Есть строка `str = '0021-0022-0023'`.

Как сделать, что бы если после каждого знака `-`, число добавлялось в новый словарь или строку.

```
list1 = 0021
list2 = 0022
list3 = 0023
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно разбить строку по разделителю "-" и получить список строк.

```
foo = "0021-0022-0023"
items = foo.split("-")
# items
# ['0021', '0022', '0023']
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, Ваш ответ дал понять как сделать провекру дальше. Мне просто надо каждое полученно число сранвивать с разными переменными. Что-то я раньше не додумался